# Compact Framework - OpenNetCf.Net FTP Samples?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, ftp, windows-mobile-5.0, opennetcf

I am trying to get the OpenNetCF.Net FTP Components working with my PDA application. I am struggling to get it doing any more than connecting to the server and wondered if anyone knew of any sample code I could use to learn how to use it with?

I need to be able to download and upload files, as well as determining the download size of any files that I wish to download.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the answer:

http://community.opennetcf.com/competition/folders/opennetcfnetftp/entry64583.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I don't like the classes in the OpenNETCF.Net.FTP namespace (the ones in the Smart Device Framework).  They're based on streams just like the full framework version (which is why we did them that way) but I find usage to be confusing (though any desktop FTP sample should work as a basis).  I wrote a [complete FTP set of classes](http://ftp.codeplex.com/) from the RFC but with an object model that I find far more intuitive that is in the OpenNETCF Community Forums.  Comes with full source.

Comment: Chris, you say you don't like classes in OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp namespace and yet your link goes to download OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp.zip.
Isn't it the same thing? am confused....

Comment: No, they are not the same.  OpenNETCF.Net.Ftp is a namespace in the SDF.  Those functions work, but I find them convoluted.  They are modelled after the desktop FTP stuff, which I also find convoluted.  The FTP class I link to is an older library I wrote that I think is a lot more logical and easier to use.