# Using Webclient on Windows Ce;

Tags: c#, ftp, compact-framework, windows-ce

im trying to develop an app for a win CE mobile device that downloads an exe file from an ftp server,and the problem is,i cant seem to reach webclient class and i am using system.net library...Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class simply doesn't seem to be supported.  See: [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). If you need to use FTP, you could try using the FTP class linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/352657/455678).

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, the WebClient class is a member of the System assembly, not System.Net

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: `Confusing is subjective` That's true. It makes perfect sense to not include webclient in `System.Web` - Otherwise it would not be available on the Client Profile.